# Securely UPDATE or INSERT row 'owned' by currently logged in User

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm trying to figure out how to structure this db:

[image]

I have table `Users`, table `Galleries` and table `Images` .

Once a user logs in I store his id as `$_SESSION[user_id]`

---

Table `Galleries` has column user_id to store who owns it.

Table `Images` has gallery_id to store which gallery they belong to.

On the client side when I want to upload a new image into Images, I use the current gallery 
id to set the `gallery_id` of the image.

The problem with that is that someone can tamper the data and upload an image into someone else's  gallery by changing the `gallery_id`.

Should I add a `user_id` in the images table as well and check against `$_SESSION[user_id]` or maybe generate a completely unique id for each  image, gallery and user and use that on the client side OR maybe i could join all 3 tables and then check against `user_id`?

What is the best practice?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gallery_id column in the images table is NOT NULL then you may be able to do something like this

```
INSERT INTO images (gallery_id,image_file) 
    SELECT id,'$image_file'
    FROM Galleries 
    WHERE id = $gallery_id AND user_id = {$_SESSION[user_id]}
```

I'm pretty sure (without testing) that the SELECT will return gallery_id as NULL if the $gallery_id and $_SESSION['user_id'] don't match any rows and thus the INSERT will fail.

Comment: this doesn't work because Galleries goes not have gallery_id column. I changed it to just id but still INSERTs regardless of what gallery id I provoide

Comment: @miro Sorry, gallery_id was a typo. Is the gallery_id in the images table NOT NULL?

Comment: It WORKS!!! :) The reason it didn't the first time is because I was faking with a gallery id that was still owned by this user :) So the worst they can do is change the gallery id of their own galleries (which the interface provides as well :) Awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, before you actually accept the uploaded file and add a record to the `images` table - you just perform a tiny check if the user is the correct one with query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Galleries WHERE id = $gallery_id AND user_id = {$_SESSION[user_id]}
```

If this query returns not `0` - then everything is fine, continue processing. Abort otherwise

Comment: That seems secure. Is there a one line (insert and check) solution?Idk... I was told to use as little queries as possible. :) Otherwise I'll use that.

Comment: @miroL the query I provided is one line. And it wouldn't harm the performance at all

Comment: I was asking about insert and check in in one query like the post below. But I couldn't get it to work so I'll use this one.

Answer (score -1):

To paraphrase you - **The problem with that is that someone can tamper the data and upload an image into someone else's gallery by changing the gallery_id.**

You are storing the `user_id` in a session variable, why not store `gallery_id` in the session as well...this will prevent accidental tampering of data flow by the end user.

By passing `gallery_id` in the url / by presenting the `gallery_id` to the user, there will always be a chance of abuse. Since this variable change directly affects your data (it's not read only, it modifies data), its not a good idea to propagate openly, leaving it to manipulations / data integrity errors.

Comment: Users can have more than 1 gallery. So they can choose which one to upload into. I need to expose the id to the client to know which one is selected... I think

Comment: @miro - ok, so we can do it in the following way:(Just thinking aloud)...give the user the option to choose a gallery from his collection of galleries...once (s)he selects it, save it in the session and do your processing. If they want to change galleries, you can always provide them with a `Change Gallery` link, which can show the user his/her galleries. He chooses, you save/edit the choice in the session and process next steps...all i say is **don't** pass this variable in the url...this will always nullify your safety mechanisms. Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm, a downvote! would someone please explain what i did wrong. Just for future refs.

Comment: It wasn't me to downvote but It might be because you said: "don't pass this variable in the url" and it really doesn't matter whether you POST or GET the data. With a simple plugin you can tamper all the data send to the server. So security must come from  the server logic. Not trough security trough obscurity > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Obviously you were not following this principle, because if you did, you wouldn't have had to ask this question in the first place. Any, i learned from this...you got your solution. Good luck.